# htaccess url rewriting, ignoring files

Tags: php, apache, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, pretty-urls

I am trying to come up with a rewrite rule, but I am having problems.

What I need - any url that starts with `/services/XXX` to be redirected to `/services/api.php?service=XXX`

I also want to ignore any files or folders that might also match.

What I have so far:

`RewriteRule ^services/([a-z]+)$ /services/api.php?service=$1 [NC, L]`

But this does not work at all, it shows a 404 page saying that file is missing when I test it.
Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To ignore the files that exists just ignore the "RewriteCond"s.

Just rewrite everything that comes into services/ to api.php?service ...

Put this into your services folder.

Be careful with your encoding, save the file as .htaccess with a encode that your server reads.

```
# .htaccess mod_rewrite

RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ api.php?service=$1 [QSA,L]
```

If you don't need to avoid Files, then just go to:

```
# .htaccess mod_rewrite

RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ api.php?service=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Comment: That works! Thanks so much!
If I only want to avoid files (but not directories and links), I just remove this line: `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f` from you second example, right?

Comment: Yeap!
-d = Folder
-f = File
-s = File not empty (it's cool but doesn't work in windows server don't know why)
-l Symbolic link
-F File accessible (via subrequest))
-U URL accessible (via subrequest))