# Query to get multiple results from URL path

Tags: mysql

From the URL 'http://www.example.com/community/teams/photo-gallery'. Using the path `/community/teams/photo-gallery` how can I query the database to get the results of the menu. Please note that the menu slug are not unique.

So that means only results about `community`, `teams`, `photo-gallery` should show.

**Here is my attempt**

```
SELECT * FROM menu WHERE menu_slug = 'community' AND menu_slug = 'teams' AND menu_slug = 'photo-gallery'
```

**This Query won't work in my situation**

```
SELECT * FROM menu WHERE menu_slug = 'community' OR menu_slug = 'teams' OR menu_slug = 'photo-gallery'
```

**Database Struture**
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
SELECT * FROM menu WHERE menu_slug = 'community' OR menu_slug = 'teams' OR menu_slug = 'photo-gallery';
```

OR

```
SELECT * FROM menu WHERE menu_slug IN ('community', 'teams', 'photo-gallery');
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but in my issue it won't work since my `menu_slug` is not unique.

Answer (score 0):

Just it? o.o

```
SELECT * FROM menu WHERE menu_slug = 'community' OR menu_slug = 'teams' OR menu_slug = 'photo-gallery'
```

Or you're talking about this?
[htaccess url rewriting, ignoring files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29761884/htaccess-url-rewriting-ignoring-files/29762635?noredirect=1#comment47657040_29762635)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but in my issue it won't work since my `menu_slug` is not unique.

Comment: @Red Virus What do you mean? You mean that you want to do a Wildcard search? Post the error you get